# Passing function to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

Can i pass a function to innerHTML ??
I thought of passing a function name data() to the innerHTML. Is it possible ??
I want a button to be created and that button should display a table when clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data();

data()
{
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nope, what you have is invalid, and innerHTML only accepts strings.

Comment: A new language is born

Comment: So, Ok thanks !! So How can I show a table with the help of try button ?? Please help me with that.

Comment: @RoyiNamir : please help me with this !!

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data();
}

function data()
{
var html = '<table>';
  html += '<tr>';
    html += '<th>Month</th>';
    html += '<th>Savings</th>';
  html += '</tr>';
  html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>January</td>';
    html += '<td>$100</td>';
  html += '</tr>';
html += '</table>';
return html
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try this code you have put onclick="myFunction" ,, it has to be onclick="myFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function, not just evaluate the identifier:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

The function that you use for the content has to contain Javascript, not HTML code. It should return a string that can be used by the `innerHTML` property:

```
data()
{
  return '<table>' +
  '  <tr>' +
  '    <th>Month</th>' +
  '    <th>Savings</th>' +
  '  </tr>' +
  '  <tr>' +
  '    <td>January</td>' +
  '    <td>$100</td>' +
  '  </tr>' +
  '</table>';
}
```